# Line graph doesnt show the y value labels

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in R and is trying to create line graph. I've been trying this for hours and still cannot understand why my y axis labels doesnt show.I've done this multiple times and stuck. Please help!

```html
# Define vector
RR <- c(1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.04, 1.08, 1.12, 1.16, 1.21, 1.23)

# Calculate range from 1 to max value 
g_range <- range(1, RR)

# Plot using y axis that ranges from 1 to max 
plot(RR, type="o", col="blue", ylim=g_range, 
     axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE)

# Make x axis 
axis(1, las=2, at=1:9, lab=c("40-45","45-50","50-55","55-60","60-65","65-70","70-75","75-80","80-"))

     
# Make y axis with horizontal labels that display ticks
axis(2, las=1, at=1:6,lab=c("1.00","1.05","1.10","1.15","1.20","1.25"))

# Create box around plot
box()
```

Comment: Your `at` is tell it to place then values at 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 (for y axis) but the plot only goes up to 1.23 so you can't see any of them except the first. Change `at` to values where you actually want them... for y `at=c(1,1.05,1.1,1.15,1.2,1.25)`

Comment: Given the code you posted, `RR` is providing the y-values. The x-values are just the indices of `RR`, that is to say, `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)`. Thus, you have no y-values greater than 1.23. But you are placing the breaks at 1, 2..., 6. Compare the results of `plot(RR, type="b")` and `plot(x=1:9, y=RR, type="b")`

Comment: thank u so much. i now understand what u both meant! :)